# Error on mysql_real_escape_string()

Tags: php, mysql-real-escape-string

That is the part of my code :

```
 if(!isset($_GET['username']) || !isset($_GET['sessionid']))
 {
  $returning = array('error' => 'Invalid query');
  echo json_encode($returning);
  break;
 }
 echo $_GET['username'];
 $z = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['username']);
 echo $z;
```

And my query :

> tymonradzik.pl/THUNDER_HUNTER/thapi.php?q=xxx&username=ty221&sessionid=JRHjYqeZKBPq1LPPck0XrnCwJU2UKnfufWNem1d7D3yEOnu0HvX9SAFCuIxe6MImJwA6xNdbQLPF9kGRPE0IeGkJoRXvEGRncrtKfGV6sLLB5ssV6sDk9X3xP13tHUQU

It is returning only "ty221", but should "ty221ty221". Where is the error ?

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: On my server error messages are disabled, but `php -l myfile.php`, gives no error

Comment: You do not have a valid connection to the database, therefore `mysql_real_escape_string` attempts to open a new connection using the configuration values in php.ini, which fails.

Comment: @DCoder post that as an answer

Comment: **Can you tell me why did you downvote my question ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://us.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string):

> If the link identifier is not specified, the last link opened by `mysql_connect()` is assumed. If no such link is found, it will try to create one as if `mysql_connect()` was called with no arguments. If no connection is found or established, an `E_WARNING` level error is generated.
>
> Returns the escaped string, or `FALSE` on error.

An educated guess is that you do not have a valid connection to the database, therefore `mysql_real_escape_string` attempts to open a new connection using the configuration values in `php.ini`, which fails.

---

Obligatory security notice:

> You are using [an **obsolete** database API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use [a modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php). You are also **vulnerable to** [**SQL injection attacks**](http://bobby-tables.com/) that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.